# Como unir dois data.frames no R com variáveis diferentes e fora de ordem?

Tags: r, data, data.frame, dplyr

Tenho dois data.frames:

```
frame1 <- data.frame(dia=c("02/01/2017","03/01/2017","04/01/2017","05/01/2017"), y=c(2,2,1,2),w=c(4,4,2,2),z=c(25,16,24,30), k=c("sim","nao","sim","nao"))
frame2 <- data.frame(dia=c("05/01/2017","04/01/2017","03/01/2017","02/01/2017"), v1=c(1000,2000,3000,4000))
```

Como faço para unir o segundo data.frame ao primeiro? É necessário deixar as datas na mesma ordem em ambos os data.frames antes de uni-los?

Tentei usar a função `rbind`, mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Imagino que você queira unir os dois data frames por colunas. A função `rbind()` (r de row) uni por linhas e a função `cbind()` (c de column) por colunas.

Para usar a função `cbind()`, terá que ordenar antes:

```
# order
frame2 <- frame2[order(match(frame2[,1],frame1[,1])),]
# unir data frames
cbind(frame1, frame2[2])
```

Uma maneira mais fácil, sem precisar ordernar, é usando a função `merge()`:

```
merge(frame1, frame2, by = "dia")

         dia y w  z   k   v1
1 02/01/2017 2 4 25 sim 4000
2 03/01/2017 2 4 16 nao 3000
3 04/01/2017 1 2 24 sim 2000
4 05/01/2017 2 2 30 nao 1000
```